# Physical activity and blood pressure

Tags: blood-pressure, sports

Apparently physical activity can significantly raise blood pressure.

Is prolonged strenuous physical activity (8hrs+) a risk factor for the effects of high blood pressure?

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE, tmsg! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. Personalised medical advice is off-topic here. You may improve your question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what in my question pertains to trying to get "Personalised medical advice" and I have no idea how I can improve the question. Basically what I am asking is whether a lot of physical activity would constitute a risk factor for high BP. If the answer to that question is "Personalised medical advice" then simply close the question.

Comment: OK. First paragraph could be read as just that in disguise along with you worrying about your BP, giving these personal numbers. Just a precaution. – Improvement for this Q is still possible by reading [ask] and documenting (with links) a bit of your prior research. – This does not criticise the content or goal of your question. Just a little nudge. Interesting reasoning.

Comment: You need to ask yourself why blood pressure rises with exercise, and how different that is from at rest.

Comment: [The opposite is true](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2017/mar/17/tsimane-of-the-bolivian-amazon-have-worlds-healthiest-hearts-says-study).

Comment: Well... I am wary of medical studies, for a host of reasons (not because I think science is bollocks, not at all. I am a physicist myself. It's more to do with the fact that statistics are often abused in those studies.). Anyway... there's the old problem of causation vs correlation. The researchers themselves hint at this: "[we] cannot yet say whether diet or the active lifestyle is the more important component." I am simply not sure whether 8hrs with a somewhat higher blood pressure than at rest is, day in, day out, overall a Good Thing or not.